# Pygame window is not responding after just making it

Tags: python, pygame

I wanted to make a game using pygame and I started my code making the pygame window

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 1000))
```

But every time I run the program, my pygame window does not respond.
Does anyone know what is happening, this did happen to me on previous codes too but it wasn't all the time like it is now

Comment: I guess your game loop is missing.

Answer (score 4):

you need a game loop to start the game and you need events to work on.
for python code i suggest:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 1000))
start_game = True
while start_game:
    print("Game Started!")
```

and for the events you can use this code in the while loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        print("mouse button up pressed")
```

the source of this code is : [RipTutorial](https://riptutorial.com/pygame/example/18046/event-loop)

Comment: I know but shouldn't the window work even though the game didn't start?

Comment: @Ericcosta the loop is there to make the window of the game showing, without the loop, it's just a normal python code.
The game actually starts but since the execution is fast (no loop to keep the execution running) the code finishes the execution of all the commands and closes the window

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think it would be better to instruct the OP to (also) handle the event `pygame.QUIT`, because otherwise the program cannot be closed without forcibly interrupting the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by 'my pygame window does not respond' you mean that you believe the window is not displaying. I think that you are just missing it because it is closing too quickly.

The window does display, but because your program ends right after you create the window, the window is immediately closed again. This is likely just happening so quickly that you are not noticing it. If you want to see this, then just put a call to `sleep` after opening the window and you will see the window sit there until the sleep expires and then it will close.

If you do not mean that and you are seeing the window but expecting it to respond, then I do not understand what you expect it to respond to. You do not have any code that tries to make it respond to anything.

EDIT:
I just noticed that @AnassABEA suggests that in a comment under his answer, though not in his answer. @AnassABEA you should update your answer to include this since I believe that is the actual answer to his question, not the missing event loop.

Comment: thank you for the additional detail but i suggested adding the while loop and said it was missing because using 'sleep' will only pause the execution for the specified time but using the will loop will be usefull in the rest of the program. I believe your reply is indeed an answer but it will not be usefull later on to complete the code.

Comment: @AnassABEA I was not attempting to tell him what to do to write the rest of his program. I assume he is able to do that. The question he seemed to be asking was why his window was not showing up, though it was but was just going away fast and that is the actual answer. Adding the loop is not the answer to OP's question, it just prevents the program from closing as would a sleep. The sleep was not intended to be a solution, just a way to demonstrate to the OP that the program exiting was the issue and allow the OP to see the window come up, wait and then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below to your code:

```
run = True
while run:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
pygame.quit()
```

Lines 4 to 5 of the code are for closing pygame when the window is closed.